# Etiquettes while listening to Friday khutbah

Tags: hadith, sunnah, jumuah

What are the etiquettes in Islam of listening to the Friday khutbah? 
For example, is it allowed to sleep while the khutbah is going on? Is it allowed to pray sunnah salaat during it?

What are the other etiquettes?

Please provide answer with authentic references.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer to this question from "Selected Friday Sermons."
[image]

This answer is word for word so I won't bother putting everything in quotations.

---

Among the acts that Muslims were commanded on Friday are:

> 1. Reciting the Qur'an, Dhikr (remembering Allah), Dua' (supplication) and invoking Allah to bestow His mercy and blessings on the Messenger
>      (SAW), as the Sunnah indicated the legislation of this.
>
>    2. Muslims should take a Ghusl (bath(, use Siwak (an eastern tree) branch to clean the teeth and wear perfume and the best and cleanest
>         clothes they have before departing for the the Jumu'ah Prayer.
>    3. It is recommended that one should clip his nails for Jumu'ah.
>    4. It is recommended to recite Surah (chapters) As-Sajdah (32) and Al-Insan (76) during the Dawn prayer of Friday after reciting the
>         Al-Fatihah (1).
>    5. It is also recommended to go as early as possible to the mosque for Jumu'ah.
>    6. Walking to the mosque for Jumu'ah is recommended, as well as being as close to the Khatib as possible. One is required to listen to the
>         Khutbah and refrain from being busied by anything else.
>    7. Sitting in Al-Ihtiba position during Jumu'ah is disliked. This is siting on the hind end with the knees bent and held together at the
>         stomach by one's hands or whatever he is wearing. This position might
>         lead to one falling asleep while the Imam is giving Khutbah.
>    8. It is recommended for those who feel sleepy to change places in the mosque.
>    9. Those attending the Jumu'ah should not step over others (in attempts to draw near the front). This is forbidden according to some
>         of the scholars and disliked according to others. This last view is
>         due to the numerous Ahadith reported that prohibit this act.
>    10. It is not proper for Muslims to attend the Jumu'ah wearing filthy clothes or having a bad odor coming from them.
>    11. It is not proper for the Muslim to attend the prayer after eating food that causes a bad odor, such as garlic, onions, radishes, and so
>          forth.
>    12. One should not come between two people sitting next to each other, unless there is sufficient space between them that they did not
>          fill.
>    13. It is recommended for those who attend the Jumu'ah to pray as much as they can before the Khutbah, until the Imam mounts the Minbar
>    14. When the Jumu'ah is called for, (i.e., the Adhan is called) the Muslim is not allowed to busy himself with anything other than heading
>          towards the mosque to attend prayer. Therefore, selling and buying
>          while headed towards the mosque for Jumu'ah (after the Adhan is
>          called) is prohibited, according to the scholars of Islam.

Comment: +1 for the detail answer, but the qn is about friday qutbah only not the whole jum'ah prayer, pls sort it to the required answer

Answer (score 0):

[By failing in sleep You going to lose Wudu.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wudu)
Without Wudu you shouldn't not be in mosque and also you shouldn't  pray salat.
I know that if some one say a word there is failure for him Friday khutbah even If someone mentions another that does not speak during khutbah that also violate Djumah.
For this second argument I heard that so many times during khutbah, Ill try to find authentic references.

Comment: according to some scholars, sleeping for a short time doesnt make you lose wudu. http://islamqa.info/en/ref/36889